# Python regular expression to match a pattern when preceded by either start of line or whitespace

Tags: python, regex

I would like to write a regex that matches the word `hello` but only when it either starts a line or is preceded by whitespace.  I don't want to match the whitespace if its there...I just need to know it (or the start of line) is there.

So I've tried:

```
r = re.compile('hello(?<=\s|^)')
```

but this throws:

```
error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

For the sake of an example, if my string to be searched is:

```
s = 'hello world hello thello'
```

then I would like my regex to match two times...at the locations in uppercase below:

```
'HELLO world HELLO thello'
```

where the first would match because it is preceded by the start of the line, while the second match would be because it is preceded by a space.  The last 5 characters would not match because they are preceded by a `t`.

Comment: What about just `re.findall(r'\bhello\b', s)`?

Comment: Why does this work if you write it as you have, but fail if you omit the `r` before the regex string?

Comment: Without `r`, `\b` is treated as a backspace symbol.

Comment: So should regular expressions in python always be entered as raw strings?

Comment: It is best practice.

Comment: Do not use `(?:(?<=\s)|^)hello`, use `(?<!\S)` as I described in my linked post answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(?:(?<=\s)|^)hello` would be that which you want. The lookbehind needs to be in the beginning of regular expression; and it must indeed be of fixed width - `\s` is 1 character wide, whereas `^` is 0 characters, so you cannot combine them with `|`. In this case we do not need to, we just alternate `(?<=\s)` and `^`.

Notice that both of these would still match **hello**oo; if this is not acceptable, you have to add `\b` at the end.